# Access VBA to modify entry of text in form

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the proper procedure to automatically change a form field to YELLOW if the user enters RED?

I would have tried a BeforeUpdate event but the documentation says:

A run-time error will occur if you attempt to modify the data contained in the control that fired the BeforeUpdate event in the event's procedure.

That seems to defeat the objective.

example:

```
Private Sub color_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)  
    If color = "YELLOW" Then 
        color = "RED"  
    End If  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LostFocus` event.

```
Private Sub color_LostFocus()
    If color = "RED" Then
        color = "YELLOW"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `AfterUpdate()` event.

Also, I recommend you use a variable.  It's a way to avoid confusion and keep code clear, re-usable.

```
strColor = Me!Color.Value
```